# How can i remote setup java android?

Tags: java, android, remote-access

I'm making a mobile application. There is no Google Play services on the device I will use. So how can I proceed when I want to update the application remotely? Do services like AWS Amplify work? When I want to update by connecting remotely, I cannot connect TeamViewer or Anydesk from the Windows device to the Android device. I'm waiting for your recommendations.
Thanks.